# I can't read log from CallNotifier and PhoneUtils

Tags: android, logcat

i try read the log generated from "CallNotifier" and "PhoneUtils" but i can't,

i use two ways for this: both are thread (AsyncTask)

1:

```
try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains("CallNotifier")) {
                        publishProgress(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

on this way i read all catlog but i filter if the line contains "CallNotifier"

2:

```
try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -s CallNotifier");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            publishProgress(line);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                }
```

This way i filter in

> exec("logcat -s CallNotifier");

Don't work

When I filter tag generated from my app the code works. if i filter from PC in terminal i can see log from CallNotifier the problem its when i filter from Android.

Comment: You can only do this on a rooted device. By default Android does not allow Apps to access logcat data from other Apps. ADB is a member of the 'log' group which allows it to access logcat data from everyone.

Comment: Ok, thanks, the device for test is rooted, how read all logcat? what is the code? "sudo logcat -s CallNotifier" ?